# Date Time validation not working in SF1

Tags: formula

Since SFDC already provides OOB date validation , we have added this validation rule to fire in case of SF1
But following formula in the rule is not working:

```
YEAR(DATEVALUE(Due_Date__c)) > 9999
```

Any reason why?

Comment: This is not working is a vague statement and doesn't help anyone in pointing towards the problem. Could you edit your question with some more explanation or screenshots to let us visualize your problem?

Comment: The validation rule should throw the error message when date field is entered as 45678 but no error message is shown and the field value is not saved. YEAR(DATEVALUE(Due_Date__c)) - this evaluates to 45,678.00

Comment: In validation rule if your error location is set to on field, try changing it on top of the page.

Comment: Yes still not working . The record is getting saved.